# how to validate user input for game without them having to press a 'submit' button each time

Tags: swift

I've got any array of ints numbers = [3,12,9]
The user needs to type in each number. if they write the correct number, the text field resets and they type in the next number. no hitting submit button.

function so far isn't working.

```
func UserInput(textView:UITextView!)
{
    if(input == nil )
    {
        return;
    }


    var inputs = input!.text.toInt();

    var x = 0
    while (x < numbers.count){
    if( inputs != nil)
    {

        if(inputs! == numbers[x] )
        {
            println("Correct!");
            input.text = ""


            x++
            //println(x)

        }
        else
        {
            println("Incorrect!");


        }
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: try to implement the delegate method optional func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView)

Comment: Sorry i forgot that. The console logs infinitely "Incorrect!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use event `EditingChanged` from your `textField`. With that you can get live input from user this way:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    var numbers = [3,12,9]
    @IBOutlet weak var input: UITextField!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        input.addTarget(self, action:"edited", forControlEvents:UIControlEvents.EditingChanged)
    }

    func edited() {
        for item in numbers {

            if input.text == "\(item)" {
                println("correct")
                //I set here timer so if user enter correct input then it will remove text after some time
                var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.4, target: self, selector: Selector("resetText"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

            } else {
                println("incorrect")
            }
        }
    }
    //This method will call after some time use if user enter correct input
    func resetText(){
        input.text = ""
    }
}
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: so ive played around with your solution. problem is; what if they input the wrong number? since it loops through whole array each time, how would one , for example. make it 'game over' if they get it wrong.

Comment: You have to check every time when user enter anything into textField.

Comment: got it. Thanks for the concise answer

Comment: Happy to help you..:)